# How do I customize a uitableview into different sections with my current setup?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I cannot seem to wrap my head around population of different sections in a single uitableview. Is there any way I can do it with my current setup? I am willing to change the way my arrays are set up if I need to. I have a lot of useless code in here that I am going to remove later, but basically all of it works. The issue is that all sections are being loaded with all of the data stored in the `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    bannerIsVisible = NO;
    bannerView.hidden = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //NSDate Info

    self.secondsPerDay = 86400;
    self.todayDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"todayDate"];
    self.dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy"];


    self.todayString = [self.dateFormat stringFromDate:self.todayDate];


    //change to string and set to the string properties
    todaysDate.text = self.todayString;


    //initialize the arrays and the state
    self.mainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.subjectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.mainDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


    /*The UITapGestureRecognizer will make it so the program can dismiss
     the keyboard at will. */
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self
                                          action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched

        [self.subjectArray addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]arrayForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@sections",self.todayString]]];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    }
    else
    {
        self.counter++;
        // This is the first launch ever
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        AG_Storage *store = [[AG_Storage alloc] init];
        store.itemName = @"Swipe to Delete";
        NSString *storeString = store.itemName;
        self.counter++;

        NSLog(@"counter%d",self.counter);

        AG_Storage *store2 = [[AG_Storage alloc] init];
        store2.itemName = @"+ Button to Add";
        NSString *store2String = store2.itemName;
        self.counter++;


        NSString *stringStuff = @"Tap this area to add notes for the day!";
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:stringStuff forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@textView",self.todayString]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];



        [self.subjectArray addObject:@"Test"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.subjectArray forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@sections",self.todayString]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


        //allocates tempDic and gives it tasks and keys
        NSMutableDictionary *tempDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: storeString, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",0], store2String, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",1], nil];



        //Sets tempDic in mainDictionary with the key Test
        [self.mainDictionary setObject:tempDic forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.subjectArray objectAtIndex:0]]];


        //Saves mainDictionary
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.mainDictionary forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mainDictionary%@",self.todayString ]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];


    }

    [self loadInitialData];

}



- (void)loadInitialData
{
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    //call my custom class and store today's date.
    AG_Storage *theDateToday = [[AG_Storage alloc]init];
    theDateToday.todaysDate = self.todayDate;

    NSLog(@"tried loadinitialdata");
    NSMutableDictionary *mutDic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mainDictionary%@",self.todayString ]];
    NSLog(@"%@",mutDic);
    //Populate mainArray
    for (int x= 0; x < self.subjectArray.count; x++) {


        for (int y = 0; y != -99; y++) {

            NSDictionary *tempDir = [mutDic valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.subjectArray objectAtIndex:x]]];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            NSLog(@"tempDir %@",tempDir);
            NSString *tempString = [tempDir valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",y]];
            NSLog(@"tempString %@",tempString);
            if ([tempString length] != 0) {
                //add the data to the mainArray and update counter
                [self.mainArray addObject:tempString];
                NSLog(@"added to array%@", self.mainArray);
            }
            else
                y = -100;


        }
        NSLog(@"SHOULD EXIT LOOP RIGHT NOW");


    }

    NSLog(@"LOOP ENDED PROPERLY");




    /*Populate textviews which hold the user's notes. Populates
     based on the state of the program.*/
    todayTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@textView",self.todayString]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.subjectArray.count;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return self.mainArray.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [self.subjectArray objectAtIndex:section];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewer cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    //populates the table based on which view is selected.

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableViewer dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"todayCell"];
    NSString *toDoItem = [self.mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = toDoItem;

    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    cell.textLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;



    return cell;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reuse sections and try to preserve your code setup, I would recommend using a `[NSMutableArray]` of `[NSMutableArray]s`. Each `NSMutableArray` would represent a section of your table, where the `index` corresponds to the `section`

Then in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` you grab the array from the index using the `NSInteger` param.

Inside `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you access section via indexPath.section and use that on your `NSMutableArray` of sections to pull out your data. From there, you then have access to data only for that section to create your rows.

Example:

```
self.sectionArrays = [NSMutableArray new];

....


 (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return [self.sectionArrays count];

}

(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[self.sectionArrays objectAtIndex:section] count];   
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *currentSectionArray = [self.sectionArrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    ...
    NSString *toDoItem = [currentSectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    ...
    configure cell
}
```

Comment: Hmm, so am i populating `sectionArrays` with both objects from `mainArray` and `sectionArray`? I'm still a little lost haha

Comment: It looks like you're separating your objects out too much. I believe it should contain objects from both `mainArray` and `sectionArray`, but your code is a bit dense to fully grasp at a glance. You want to do this: Get all objects from `mainArray` that correspond to `sectionArray[0]`. That gets put in an array and set to `sectionArrays[0]`. Likewise, `sectionArrays[1]` = all objects from `mainArray` that belong in `sectionArray[1]`

Comment: and by `sectionArray`, I meant `subjectArray` :). To use sections, you essentially just need to cut `mainArray` nicely into smaller pieces (i.e. subarrays)

Comment: @user3430084 any luck with it? Did you get it to work?

Comment: Yes I did thank you so much! The array is giving me some problems now but I think I should be able to figure it out